# Center span with background inside div

Tags: css

```
<div>
<span style= "background: red; text-align: center;">
There is an error
</span>
</div>
```

The text align center isnt working. I want the text to be center with background.

https://jsfiddle.net/yv246re9/

Answer (score 5):

span tags are inline elements and won't center, you need to wrap the text with a element that takes the width of the content like `<p>` or `<h1>`, or you can add the **`text-align: center`** to the parent `<div>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div style="text-align: center; width:100%;">
<span style= "background: red; ">
There is an error
</span>
</div>
```

The span will be positioned in the center according to the parent div which has a width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: block;` after `text-align: center;`. The **`span`** is not a block-element but a inline-element.

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

*Have a good day !*